# TypeScript (react) : Dynamic update of object with spread operator

Tags: typescript

I have a custom type set

```
export type Menu =  {
    search: boolean,
    browse: boolean,
}
```

IM using zustand to hold state like so

```
interface AppState {
    menu: Menu;
    setMenu: (newMenu:Menu) => void
}
export const useStore = create<AppState>((set: SetState<AppState>, get: GetState<AppState>) => ({
    menu: {search: false, browse: false},
    setMenu: (newMenu:Menu):void => {
        set({menu: newMenu})
    }
}))
```

now in component i want to update this state onClick

```
const handleClick = (key: string) => {
        return (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
            setMenu({...menu, [key]: !menu[key]})
        }
    }


<div className="main-button menu-button" onClick={handleClick("search")}>
```

Logic is to simply toggle appropriate key: value pair to true or false. TypeScript throws error at

```
setMenu({...menu, [key]: !menu[key]})
```

I understand it wont allow because it cant guarantee menu[key] exists. If I hardcode / write menu['search'] it works.
What is the best course of action in this case to make it work?

Comment: `const handleClick = (key: keyof Menu) => (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
            setMenu({...menu, [key]: !menu[key]})
        };` that is to say, you restrict the type of the key to known keys of the type

Comment: Side note: `...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what rest and spread syntax do. It's not really important, but... :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `key` is of type `string`, and as you said, may be a string with a name that's not valid in the interface.

If you're always supplying these names as hardcoded values as in your example, you an make it `keyof Menu` instead (which also has the convenient effect of TypeScript telling you when you call `handleClick` with an invalid value):

```typescript
const handleClick = (key: keyof Menu) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

If you **have** to allow `string` for `key` in `handleClick`, then you could use either a type guard function or a type assertion function. Then `handleClick` would use it, either in an `if` (the type guard) or just inline (the type assertion).

Type guard:

```typescript
function isValidMenuKey(key: string): key is keyof Menu {
    return key === "search" || key === "browse";
}
// ...
const handleClick = (key: string) => {
    if (isValidMenuKey(key)) {
        return (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
            setMenu({...menu, [key]: !menu[key]});
        };
    } else {
        // Do what? (See type assertion version below)
    }
};
```

Type assertion:

```typescript
// Or type assertion:
function assertIsValidMenuKey(key: string): asserts key is keyof Menu {
    if (key !== "search" || key !== "browse") {
        throw new Error(`Invalid key for Menu: "${key}"`);
    }
}
// ...
const handleClick = (key: string) => {
    assertIsValidMenuKey(key);
    return (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
        setMenu({...menu, [key]: !menu[key]});
    };
};
```